# Pass % using IN SQL

Tags: sql

I have a query

```
select dim.name as division,dm.name as department, cuser.contractor_name, cuser.contractor_surname,d.status as status,
d.date_submission,cm.name as code,scm.name as subCode,cuser.company_name as company, gt.grade_name as grade, gm.grade_value as gradeValue
from document d, selected_grade_map sgm, selected_grade_details sgd, code_master cm,code_master scm,
contractor_user_master_ipms cuser, department_master dm, division_master dim, grade_master gm, grade_type gt
where 
convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), d.date_submission, 101)) <= convert(datetime, '2011-06-22') AND 
convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), d.date_submission, 101)) >= convert(datetime, '2010-12-22') AND
d.application_status = 'NEW' 
and d.status != 'Forked'
and d.id = sgm.doc_id 
and sgm.selected_grade_id = sgd.selected_grade_id
and sgd.code_id = cm.code_id 
and sgd.sub_code_id = scm.code_id 
and d.contractor_user = cuser.id 
and d.department_id = dm.id 
and d.division_id = dim.id 
and sgd.grade_id = gm.grade_id
and gm.grade_type_id = gt.grade_type_id
and d.department_id IN ('%')
and dim.id IN (1,2)
and cm.code_id like '%' 
and scm.code_id like '%' 
and gt.grade_type_id like '%'
and d.status like '%'
and cuser.reservation_category like '%'
and cuser.company_name like '%'
```

Situation is that ..
User can select multiple criteria as filter but If a user does not select any filter then I need to pass all. So, I tried using `%` in SQL IN. But Here columns are integer so. It will  not allow this.

The query is static and written in iReport

How do I can use pass all in SQL like

```
d.department_id IN ('%')
```

Comment: Why are you using a conditional at all if you don't want to filter anything?

Comment: It will be decided run time from UI

Comment: So have it exclude the conditional at run-time, too.

Comment: @Flimzy -- what he does is use a plain "%" if the user does not enter any criteria for that field. Bot this works only for text fields using the LIKE expression. He wants to do something similar for an IN expression against an integer.

Comment: I understand that. My suggestion is that if he wants an IN() that includes everything, he should omit the conditional entirely. Regardless of the data type.

Comment: @James: But if the user *has* entered some criteria, they are included into the IN list. The question is, how? So far I can only conclude that the list is constructed dynamically. In that case @Flimzy's suggestion makes sense and may even turn out most sensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IN` query won't allow you to pass a string, and that string will not match on any integer because it is not in `LIKE`. Look into how your iReport can alter this part of the query dynamically.

Comment: +1. The hack with `Like '%'` is horrible even where it works. You must investigate how you can alter the query dynamically. If the combinations are not too many, maybe you can prepare several (static) alternatives to choose from.

Answer (score 3):

In case input is none can you give a dummy value like -1?

Then transform your query like

```
(  
  d.department_id IN (@Userparam) 
    OR
  (-1) IN (@Userparam) -- If you pass -1 then it returns all user departments
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The hack with `Like '%'` is horrible even where it works. You must investigate how you can alter the query dynamically.

If there is really only one integer column that you want to either filter on or not filter on, you might get away with having two static queries to select from (one that has the condition, one that does not).

Answer (score 0):

The % character is only special for LIKE. When you use it with = or IN(), etc, it is taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all values if your input is null you could use COALESCE

so instead of

`cm.code_id like '%'`

use

`cm.code_id = COALESCE(@inputvalue, cm.code_id)`

COALESCE will select the first non-null value. So if you give a null input it will select itself.

[COALESCE Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: what if he needs IN (i.e. there are multiple values)?

Comment: The question asked how can he pass all. If I am understanding correctly the d.department_id IN ('%') was an attempt and loading everything if nothing exists.

Comment: But you are not addressing the `IN ('%')` problem in your answer. I mean, you are offering a replacement for `LIKE '%'`, not for `IN ('%')`.

Comment: The solution to handle the IN('%') would be dependent upon the sql platform. For instance ms-sql I have used method from parsing a csv string to using tables to query the in(). You are correct that my above solution only takes half the problem into account.

Answer (score -1):

You could possibly try doing something similar with "BETWEEN". Default to BETWEEN(0,9999) and substitute BETWEEN(100,100) if the user enters department 100.

However the best advice would be to tailor the SQL to each query if that's possible using your language in your environment.

If you are in a more constrained environment where you can only use static SQL it may make more sense to write three or four simpler queries with fewer substitutions.

Comment: I think BETWEEN will not work as he needs IN eg IN(1,5,7). I agree that building the query as you mention is the best choise.

Comment: I am aware of that but I don't see how he can pass in a variable list -- unless he builds a new SQL string.